# Can't set height of MPAndroidChart HorizontalBarChart

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I am trying to set the height of a HorizontalBarChart widget in MPAndroidChart. The only height related method you can call on a HorizontalBarChart object is `setMinimumHeight()` which didn't seem to help. I've also tried setting the HorizontalBarChart to `400dp` but it seems this value is ignored and chart still takes up more space than it actually needs. How can I set the height of this chart?

[image]

**Implementation:**

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="home">

<com.demo.companion.widgets.VerticalTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_device_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:text="Watch Name"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textSize="65sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_watch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/watch" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_bluetooth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iv_watch"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_device_name">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bluetooth" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bluetooth_status"
        style="@style/FTUEBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Bluetooth Connected" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check" />
</RelativeLayout>

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
    android:id="@+id/vitals"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_bluetooth"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_device_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

protected HorizontalBarChart mChart;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mChart = (HorizontalBarChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vitals);

    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(true);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(false);

    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    mChart.getXAxis().setSpaceMax(5f);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);

    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    setData(4, 100);
    mChart.setFitBars(true);
    mChart.animateY(1000);

    return rootView;
}

private void setData(int count, float range) {

    float barWidth = 0.5f;
    float spaceForBar = 2f;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        float val = (float) (Math.random() * range);
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i * spaceForBar, val,
                null));
    }

    BarDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null &&
            mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet)mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "DataSet 1");
        set1.setBarShadowColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        set1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

        set1.setDrawIcons(false);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setBarWidth(barWidth);
        mChart.setData(data);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting margins in the xml file:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
    android:id="@+id/vitals"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"     <!-- adjust -->
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"        <!-- accordingly -->
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_bluetooth"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_device_name" />
```

Edit ::

```
mChart.setExtraTopOffset(-155);
```

Comment: This doesn't get me quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to eliminate the extra white space above the chart. Settings a negative top margin does get me a bit closer.    android:layout_marginTop="-155dp"